# React state from HOC and component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, higher-order-components

I have a form with controlled inputs managed via a Higher Order Component. The structure is like this:

#### Field Higher Order Component

```
function BaseField(WrappedComponent) {
  class WrappedField extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: '',
        active: false,
      }
    }

    setValue = (e) => {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value })
    }
    ...
    <WrappedComponent
      {...this.props}
      value={this.state.value}
      set={this.setValue}
      active={this.state.active}
    />
    ....
```

#### Field

```
import React from 'react';
import BaseField from './BaseField';

const TextField = (props) => {
  return <input
    value={props.value}
    onChange={props.set}
    name={props.name}
    type={props.type}
  />
}

export default BaseField(TextField);
```

When using `TextField` this works well - however, I want to use this with more flexibility - for example, I'd like to be able to enhance the `onChange` functionality in some cases, always having it set state but **also** have it do other things based on state or functions in the component the `TextField` is used in.

Am I misunderstanding how HOCs work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like [`createChainedFunction`](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/master/src/utils/createChainedFunction.js) from [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap):

```
function createChainedFunction(...funcs) {
  return funcs
    .filter(f => f != null)
    .reduce((acc, f) => {
      if (typeof f !== 'function') {
        throw new Error('Invalid Argument Type, must only provide functions, undefined, or null.');
      }

      if (acc === null) {
        return f;
      }

      return function chainedFunction(...args) {
        acc.apply(this, args);
        f.apply(this, args);
      };
    }, null);
}
```

and something from my react utils:

```
export function copyPropsWithout(props, without) {
  const propKeys = Object.keys(props);
  const passProps = propKeys.reduce((obj, propKey) => {
    if (without.indexOf(propKey) === -1) {
      obj[propKey] = props[propKey];
    }

    return obj;
  }, {});

  return passProps;
}
```

I'd add these to your utils and then use them like:

```
 ...
    <WrappedComponent
      {...copyPropsWithout(this.props, ['onChange'])}
      value={this.state.value}
      set={createChainedFunction(this.setValue, this.props.onChange}}
      active={this.state.active}
    />
    ....
```